# Set Looper for user-defined handler

Tags: android, handler, android-thread

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Above code creates a handler with MainLooper.

But if I have a custom handler

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler implements IHandler { 
    ... 
}
```

How can I attach MyHandler to the MainLooper?

Thank you!

Comment: `new MyHandler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

Comment: This does not work.   Because MyHandler does not have a constructor take Looper as parameter.

Comment: Then add one. If you do not accept a `Looper`, then you are relying on [deprecated constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler), anyway.

Comment: public MyHandler(Looper looper) { ..  }.  // What should I put to attach the Handler to the main Looper?  I dont know how to set Looper. Thank you!

Comment: "What should I put to attach the Handler to the main Looper?" -- a call to `super(looper);`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html